# Unknown class GADBannerView in Interface Builder file

Tags: ios, storyboard, admob

I have a `GADBannerView` in my storyboard file. My project is pure swift (except for some 3rd party pods).

---

I have tried with all the three pods recommended:

1. Firebase/Core + Firebase/AdMob
2. Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK
3. GoogleMobileAds

I have also tried adding `-all_load -ObjC` linker flags.

---

I keep on getting this error in my logs:

```
Unknown class _TtC11Checkvistle13GADBannerView in Interface Builder file.
```

I suspect `use_frameworks` in my Podfile since I am not sure if these pods play well being frameworks. Though I am not sure anymore about the problem.

Comment: `_TtC11Checkvistle13GADBannerView`, what kind of class is this exactly?

Comment: @DanielStorm It's a mangled name. My module is named `Checkvistle` and the class name is `GADBannerView`.